# Why this program outputs 4?

Tags: c

Using define preprocessor directive why following program outputs 4 instead of 3?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX(A,B)((A)>(B)) ? A : B

int max_t(int a, int  b)
{
  return ((a)>(b)) ? a : b; 
}

int main()
{
  int i=1;
  int j=2;
  int val = MAX(++i, ++j); // this outputs 4 but why?
  //int val = max_t(++i, ++j);
  printf("%d\n", val);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because that's the way preprocessor directives work.

Comment: @Ashelly Can you please explain?

Comment: @eyllanesc *no*. Not that one. Here there is no undefined behaviour.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I understand, you are right. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Macros are just replacements by tokens so

```
MAX(++i, ++j);
```

expands to

```
((++i) > (++j)) ? ++i : ++j;
```

As you see the parameters are evaluated (and incremented) twice in this case and therefore the output is `4`.

Comment: That is what I wanted to know.

Answer (score 3):

```
 int main()
 {
   int i=1;
  int j=2;
  int val = ((++i)>(++j)) ? ++i : ++j;

   printf("%d\n", val);
  return 0;
 }
```

This is what happening after preprocessor stage  (After Macro expansion) and you can check this by "cc -E file.c -o file.i" command in linux gcc compiler , this expanded code is at last of the file .

so here : val = (2 > 3 ? 3 : 4 ) , this 4 get stored into val , thats why val = 4.